# Please help me understand Boost::Any

Tags: c++, boost

`Boost::Any` uses a generalized base class `placehoder` from which derive the templated `holder` class. `placehoder` offers an interface with virtual methods, notably a method to retrieve the typeid of what the any contains. The any then contains a pointer to a `placeholder`. What I don't understand is the purpose of `placeholder` and the use of virtual methods. Let this simplified construct of `any` (for which the interface's source is available [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/any.hpp)) :

```
class any
{
public:
    template<typename ValueType>
    any(const ValueType & value) : content(new holder<ValueType>>(value)) {}

private:
    class placeholder
    {
    public:
        virtual const std::type_info & type_info() const = 0;
    };

    template<typename ValueType>
    class holder : public placeholder
    {
    public:
        holder(const ValueType &value) : held(value) {};
        virtual const std::type_info &type_info() const
        {
            return typeid(ValueType);
        }
        const value_type held;
    };

    placeholder *content;
}
```

It looks to me like `placeholder` could completly be removed and `placeholder *content;` substituted with `holder *content;`.

Moreover, I don't understand the mechanism of assignment used in `any`. Let :

```
any & operator=(any rhs)
{
    any(rhs).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

Which asigns an `any` to another. This will construct a temporary `any` with `rhs`'s `content` and `swap` it with the current object, effectively doing what we want but... What becomes the point of all of this if `any` just systematically constructs a new, temporary `any` and affect it to the current object for all assignment operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It looks to me like placeholder could completely be removed and placeholder *content; 
>   substituted with holder *content;.

Nope, since `holder` is a templated class this is invalid:

```
holder * content
```

You need to write

```
holder<T> * content
```

but you dont know `T` - (which is the whole point of `boost::any`).
So instead you create a common base class for all the `holder<T>` classes - which is what `placeholder` is.

> Moreover, I don't understand the mechanism of assignment used in any. Let :

```
any & operator=(any rhs)
{
    any(rhs).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

This is the commonly known "copy and swap" idiom. Consider what a more standard implementation would look like:

```
any & operator=(const any &rhs)
{
    //Watch out for self-assignment.
    if(&any==this) return *this;

    //Clean out the old data
    delete content;

    // Update our content
    content = rhs.content->clone();

    return *this;
}
```

This duplicates a lot of behaviour in the copy constructor. The copy and swap idiom is a way to remove that duplication. The copying is done by the copy-constructor and the cleanup is done by the temporary destructor.

I do think its odd that the `operator=` gets a copy as its argument since it's not accepting a const reference, and then creates a second copy from that one. I would have expected either:

```
any & operator=(const any & rhs)
{
    any(rhs).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

or

```
any & operator=(any rhs)
{
    rhs.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```